# I need help using doxia sink.link() to generate html in mvn custom report

Tags: java, html, maven

I am attempting to generate links on my mvn report page using the sink.link(String text) method.  My code looks like this:

```
sink.link("json-schema/ClusterStatusMessage.schema.json");
sink.link_();
```

This is resulting in an html snippet that looks like this:

```
<a href="json-schema/ClusterStatusMessage.schema.json"></a>
```

I want the html snippet to look like this

```
<a href="json-schema/ClusterStatusMessage.schema.json">Link Display Text Here</a>
```

So that the link will actually be displayed.  Unfortunately I have been unable to make the call to .link(...) do what I want.  I suspect I need to pass in a SinkEventAttributes, but am unsure which fields to set.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
sink.link("json-schema/ClusterStatusMessage.schema.json");
sink.text("Link Display Text Here");
sink.link_();
```